# Reassigning sorted NSManagedObjects to the NSSet

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm just getting started with Core Data and am not sure how this works.  I basically have a Person entity and an alarm entity. Each person can have many alarms.  What I want is to go to a detailViewController of the person object and see their alarms.  Because NSSet isn't sorted,  I have a method to return the alarms sorted like so:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedTimes {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Alarm" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *timeDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[timeDescriptor]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Can I do this???
    //self.person.alarms = [NSSet setWithArray:objects];

//    for (NSManagedObject *obj in objects) {
//        NSDate *date = [obj valueForKey:@"time"];
//        NSLog(@"date: %@", [date description]);
//    }
    return objects;
}
```

What I'm wondering is, in the line `self.person.alarms = [NSSet setWithArray:objects];` is that ok?  I guess I'm not sure as to what actually is happening.  My executeFetchRequest returns an array of the objects I want.  Can I just go ahead and assign it to the person entity's alarm property?  I wasn't sure if there was a relationship from Person->Alarm that I should not be mucking with, or if something like this is perfectly legal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your fetch request returns *all* alarms, not only the alarms of `self.person`. You have to add an predicate to the fetch request:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person = %@", self.person];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

(assuming that `person` is the inverse relationship from the *Alarm* entity to the *Person* entity). But you don't really need a fetch request to get the sorted alarms of a person. A more direct way is

```
NSArray *objects = [[self.person.alarms allObjects]
                              sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[timeDescriptor]];
```

Now to your question: The statement

```
self.person.alarms = [NSSet setWithArray:objects];
```

just re-assigns the same set of alarms to the person. This effectively does not change anything, because it is the same set. In particular, it does not guarantee that `self.person.alarms` will now be sorted by time.

*Remark:* It you want to display a table view with the alarms of a person, you can also use a `NSFetchedResultsController` (FRC) as table view data source. The advantage of using a FRC is that the table view is automatically updated if objects are inserted, removed or updated.

Have a look at the `NSFetchedResultsController` and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` documentation which contains all the required code templates.